# Writing an LightSwitch HTML client, how to prevent Primary Key validation?

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

Today I played a little bit with LightSwitch in VisualStudio 2012. I've following problem:

I have a database created by EntityFramework (code first) with GUIDs as the primary key on every table.

I used this database as the data source for my LightSwitch project.

Now on creating a new item with LightSwitch, of course I want to hide the primary key from the user, as it is generated by the database. Unfortunately the gui keeps validating the field, even if I remove it from the screen. I can't save a new item, because the validation wants me to enter a value for the primary key field.

I think I'm not using a totally uncommon setup, so how to solve this simple problem?

I've already tried to pre-populate the guid in the created event on the server side, but even if I include the field on the screen, it is still empty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the created code isn't actually run until you try and first insert the entity (which it won't ever reach due to the validation error)

The solution I found (which isn't ideal) is to populate the id with javascript with an empty guid ("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")] and then overwriting it in entity_inserting(..)

It's not ideal is as the client will get confused as the ID on the server is different from it's ID.

Supposedly, one should generate the IDs in the database, but I haven't had any luck with that.

Comment: could you please provide the source code for this? I have same problem and I have trouble finding that entity_Inserting method

Answer (score 1):

Another solution I found, which is a bit nicer, is to set up a controller that serves GUIDs and then fetch those guids clientside.

This will allow the client to be able to reference the object without a page refresh.

If you want some code to do it, just comment or upvote or something..